# FileZilla Errors error 550, error 501

Tags: java, android, file-upload, ftp, filezilla

Hi everyone i installed filezilla ftp server to my pc. I am tryin to upload a file on android application. However, I am getting error 550 which is directory not found and error 501 which is syntax error. I made some search on the internet but I did not find the solution. Could you please help me? And also here is the log on the FileZilla İnterface:

```
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:07 - (not logged in) (192.168.10.179)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:07 - (not logged in) (192.168.10.179)> 220 FTP server' a hoşgeldiniz.
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:07 - (not logged in) (192.168.10.179)> USER users
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:07 - (not logged in) (192.168.10.179)> 331 Password required for users
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:07 - (not logged in) (192.168.10.179)> PASS *******
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:07 - users (192.168.10.179)> 230 Logged on
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:07 - users (192.168.10.179)> CWD murat.alemdagtp
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:07 - users (192.168.10.179)> 550 CWD failed. "/murat.alemdagtp": directory not found.
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:07 - users (192.168.10.179)> TYPE I
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:07 - users (192.168.10.179)> 200 Type set to I
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:08 - users (192.168.10.179)> PASV
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:08 - users (192.168.10.179)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,10,179,9,71)
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:08 - users (192.168.10.179)> STOR 
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:08 - users (192.168.10.179)> 501 Syntax error
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:09 - users (192.168.10.179)> QUIT
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:09 - users (192.168.10.179)> 221 Goodbye
(000001)14.08.2012 14:36:09 - users (192.168.10.179)> disconnected.
```

Here is my uploading code:

```
public Void doInBackground(Object... arg0) 
{  

  String server = "192.168.10.179";
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      try
      {
        ftpClient.connect(server,21);
        ftpClient.login("users", "1234567");
        ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("murat.alemdag\ftp");
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(file);
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftpClient.storeFile(filename, in);
        publishProgress(100); 
        ftpClient.logout();

      }

      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }    
  return null;
 }//end of doInBackground method
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the directory entry "murat.alemdagtp" exists at all. It does not seem to. You can do so with any ftp client (like the filezilla client) and make a note which directories you can see after login without supplying a starting directory.

Then try submitting the path with a forward slash "/" instead, and lets see if that works.

Update:
Regarding you syntax error: STOR needs the remote filename as parameter. I cannot see that in the log. Have a look here: nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm#STOR

So check what the variable filename in

```
tpClient.storeFile(filename, in);
```

currently contains.

Comment: After trying with the forward slash here is the result. It is still not working. 
users (192.168.10.179)> 230 Logged on
users (192.168.10.179)> CWD murat.alemdag/ftp
users (192.168.10.179)550 CWD failed. "/murat.alemdag/ftp": directory not found.
users (192.168.10.179)TYPE I
users (192.168.10.179)200 Type set to I
users (192.168.10.179)PASV
users (192.168.10.179)227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,10,179,11,31)
users (192.168.10.179)STOR 
users (192.168.10.179)501 Syntax error
users (192.168.10.179)QUIT
users (192.168.10.179)221 Goodbye
users (192.168.10.179)disconnected.

Comment: There simply is no directory /murat.alemdag/ftp visible at the scope of the ftp server.

Comment: I created a file in my user location. Here is the location. I want to upload the files to this location. C:\Users\murat.alemdag\ftp

Comment: in addition ftpClient.storeFile() is not working to because the file is not uploaded.

Comment: The important part is error 501 because it does not upload the file

Comment: That might just be caused by the server not being able to switch to the correct directory. If you say "/murat.alemdag/ftp" to the server, it tries to switch to whatever the server takes for its root scope and then switch to "murat.alemdag/ftp". So if the root scope for the server is c:\Users then this should work. As long as the ftp user sees the directory. If the root directory is any different, it will not work. What are you seeing if you log in with a standard ftp client? do you then see the murat.alemdag directory?

Comment: now I worked but the uploaded file size is 0 kb and the error 501 is still repeating.

Comment: this code was working after restarting the modem it stopped. In addition when I replace filename with another string it uploads the file but its size is 0 kb! and after a while I am getting connection timeout.

Comment: do you have any idea why the file is 0 kb?

Comment: The only time I had something like that, it was an port forwarding issue with the router. If that is possible, research "Passive ftp" vs "Active ftp". It also could be, that your variable "in" is simply empty as the code could not really read the file.

Comment: But the "the code stopped working after modem restart" might indicate a port issue.

Comment: what do you suggest I am sending directly to the port 21 should I change it? By the way I think you are right about the variable in because when I change the filename with a string the file uploaded with this name but the size is still 0 kb.

Comment: FTP not only uses port 21. That is only the port for the inital handshake.

Comment: then do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Try uploading a file using a proven ftp client using possibly the same network connection as the your code uses. If that works, make super sure that the variable in really holds some data. best to do that would be file.length(). If that is 0 or throws an exception, you might not be having a file. If bot work, it would be nice to know which exact implemenatation of a ftpClient Class you are using.

Comment: still the result same it reads the file there is nothing with in variable.